# Implement JPA Default Listener without XML configuration

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot, jpa-2.1

I'm trying to implement the **Default Listeners** on JPA entities. I've read few articles and all article mentions:

> Currently, default listeners can only be specified in a mapping XML
>   file because there is no equivalent annotation

Do we have any workaround for this to implement **Default Listener** without use of XML file.

> using: Spring Boot, Spring Data JPA - (Java Configuration)

Answer (score 0):

you can either add your listenrs to on the body of your entity this way :

```
@Entity
 public class MyEntity{
      //attributes & getters and setters

      @PrePersist void onPrePersist() {}
        @PostPersist void onPostPersist() {}
        @PostLoad void onPostLoad() {}
        @PreUpdate void onPreUpdate() {}
        @PostUpdate void onPostUpdate() {}
        @PreRemove void onPreRemove() {}
        @PostRemove void onPostRemove() {}
  }
```

**OR** use the `@EntityListeners` annotation this way :

```
  @Entity
  @EntityListeners({MyListener1.class, MyListener2.class})
  public class MyEntity {

  }
```

And :

`public class MyListener1 {
    @PrePersist void onPrePersist(Object o) {}
    @PostPersist void onPostPersist(Object o) {}
    @PostLoad void onPostLoad(Object o) {}
    @PreUpdate void onPreUpdate(Object o) {}
    @PostUpdate void onPostUpdate(Object o) {}
    @PreRemove void onPreRemove(Object o) {}
    @PostRemove void onPostRemove(Object o) {}
}`

Comment: if i do this i have to add @EntityListeners on all the entity that i have.. which is not what i want to do.. Thanks for the answer

Comment: @AmanTuladhar on the first solution you don't have to add `@EntityListener`

Comment: @AmanTuladhar you can add the listeners on the entity class directly

Comment: Same problem applies as i need to add the listeners to all the entities i have.. not just one

Comment: @AmanTuladhar your question isn't clear, for instance if you want a common listener you can just configure one class and extend it on all your entities

Comment: Your last option seems to be workaround for now. I'll have a base entity and adding the listenter to base entity helped..But it not as good as default listener that we can have add with (persistence) xml file. But Thanks for now i'll be adding the listeners to base entity that i have. Cheers

Comment: But why would he want to have a common superclass for all his entities to perform quite an orthogonal task to all of them? That's just lame. I think he's very correct to try to avoid any changes to his entities.

Comment: On the other hand I have to add, that if Aman wants a common listener for different entities he probably wants them to at least implement some common interface to process them in that listener. Probably even have some common fields. In that case, making a superclass is a reasonable thing to do. However if he just wants listener to know entity class and ID, not so much.